# AWS Lambda Serverless CORS not sending expected response headers

Tags: python, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm running into CORS error for my requests from localhost. When the OPTIONS request is sent to the lambda it does not send back the headers expected.

serverless.yml:

```
functions:
  login:
    handler: login.login
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /login
          method: post
          cors:
            origin: '*'
            headers:
              - Content-Type
```

Response headers in the lambda:

```
response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({'stuff': stuff}),
        "headers": {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    }
```

But when my browser is sending an options request expected headers are nowhere to be found. These are the response header for that request:

```
apigw-requestid: <id>
content-length: 23
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 22 Jul 2021 12:04:18 GMT
```

Request headers in the request:

```
headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
```

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using custom authorizers https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#http-endpoints-with-custom-authorizers ?